# I'm trying to retrieve from a database for a select box with cakePHP but the data isn't being retrieved properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.3 
I have in the controller

```
    $employee = TableRegistry::get('employees');
    $allNames = $employee->find('list', array('employee_name' => array('employee_name') ) );
    $allNames = $allNames->toArray();
    $this->set('name', $allNames);
```

and in my template

```
    <?= $this->Form->input('employee', array('type'=>'select','label' => false,
        'options' => $name,'value'=>$name));?>
```

The only thing being retrieved and displayed is the number of entries i have in the database, $name only contains an array(1,2,3,4) when it should be actual people names.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP you are using?

Comment: I am using cakephp 3.3

Comment: <?= $this->Form->input('employee', array('type'=>'select','label' => false,
        'options' => $name));?>

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, the array $name itself doesnt contain the employee_name and is returning a number instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the [**documentation**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs) about how `find('list')` works?'

```
$allNames = $employee->find('list', [
    'keyField' =>     'employee_name'
    'valueField' => 'employee_name'
]);
$this->set('name', $allNames);

<?= $this->Form->input('employee', ['type'=>'select','label' => false,
    'options' => $name]);?>
```

Comment: This works, but the value is a number 1,2,3,4 I want the value to be the name as well...

Comment: there was a typo. is valueField and not valuefield. I edited

Comment: thank you! this solved the issue, i have been reading the documentation just been struggling to learn cakephp..though in the long run it will be much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can map id and value by `keyField` and `valueField` in list query

in your controller

```
 $employee = TableRegistry::get('employees');
 $allNames = $employee->find('list', array('valueField' =>employee_name','keyField'=>'employee_id' )); // correct employee_id with your table id field.
 $this->set('name', $allNames);
```

In your View

```
 <?= $this->Form->input('employee', array('type'=>'select','label' => false,
        'options' => $name));?>
```

Comment: This works, but the value is a number 1,2,3,4 I want the value to be the name as well...